# Launch skype from wp7 Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, skype4com

I want to launch Skype from my windows phone 7 application, I found some methods to do that using android and iPhone but could not get any kind of help how to do it in windows phone 7,
Does this possible or how can we do that?
Please share if there are some libraries available or any chunk of sample code that can help.
Thanks

Regards Zauk

Answer (score 1):

Launch Skype on Windows Phone?

In the current SDK for Windows Phone 7, it is not possible.